# Dropdown Javascript menus overlapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The goal is to, in the header, make the first two titles open as expandable dropdown menus. I have little to no experience in coding, especially javascript and jquery. I have achieved the effect for one button (https://gyazo.com/c8abca5a6c73fc5e4856e85727b57b55) and whenever I add the second one, they effectively overlap, loose format and locate themselves in the wrong positions.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/valik140795/pen/qadXOo

Code for the header (2 dropdown + 2 normal titles):

```
  <ul>
    <style>
      .dropbtn {
          background-color: #282828;
          color: #AA9568;
          padding: 0px;
          font-size: 16px;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
      }

      .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
          background-color: #282828;
      }


      .dropdown {
          position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
          display: inline-block;
      }

      .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 5px;
          z-index: 998;
          background-color: #282828;
          min-width: 180px;
          overflow: auto;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      }

      .dropdown-content a {
          color: #AA9568;
          padding: 3px 5px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
      }

      .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #282828}

      .show {display:block;}
    </style>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><a href=#fab>ФАБРИКИ</a></button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#nobilis">Nobilis</a>
        <a href="#colordeseda">Color de Seda</a>
        <a href="#eugenio">Eugenio Colombo</a>
        <a href="#libra">Libra</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      /* When the user clicks on the button,
      toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
      function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
      }

      function filterFunction() {
          var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
          input = document.getElementById("myInput");
          filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
          div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
          a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
          for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
              if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                  a[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                  a[i].style.display = "none";
              }
          }
      }
    </script>

    <li>|</li>

    <style>
      .dropbtn {
            background-color: #282828;
            color: #AA9568;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
            background-color: #282828;
        }


        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 999;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content1 {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          top: 40%;
          left: 35%;
          z-index: 999;
          background-color: #282828;
          min-width: 180px;
          overflow: auto;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: #AA9568;
            padding: 3px 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #282828}

        .show {display:inline;}
    </style>


    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="dealerFunction()" class="dropbtn"><a href=#fab>ДИЛЕРЫ</a></button>
      <div id="Dealersdropdown" class="dropdown-content1">
        <a href="#nobilis">Nobilis</a>
        <a href="#colordeseda">Color de Seda</a>
        <a href="#eugenio">Eugenio Colombo</a>
        <a href="#libra">Libra</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      /* When the user clicks on the button,
        toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function dealerFunction() {
            document.getElementById("Dealersdropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        function filterFunction() {
            var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            div = document.getElementById("Dealersdropdown");
            a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    a[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    a[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.123contactform.com/form-2178643/My-Form">Сотрудничество</a></li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Yes, I know this is untidy, however I am a novice and still in the stage of learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a bit unclear!. So what you want is that when the dropdown opens it should appear in front of the header bar. not like in your codepen example the second header is shown above the drop down. Clear this!

Comment: @QaisarRajput I want it to appear directly underneath the title and disappear whenever the mouse leaves the box.

Comment: ```<style></style>``` should only be used in the ```<head></head>``` of an HTML document.  Using the style tags outside of the head is bad practice, and can cause adverse effects.

Comment: In your codepen, you have javascript and CSS in the HTML.  Think of HTML as content, CSS as style, and Javascript as behavior.  They should all be separated.  Read: [web standards model](https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_web_standards_model_-_HTML_CSS_and_JavaScript)

Comment: @Tiffany https://codepen.io/valik140795/pen/qadXOo

Comment: @Valbone is there a reason for having two sections of ```<style></style>```? If you're wanting to change the style of an element based on an event, you should be using Javascript, because that's a behavior.  Also, is there a reason why you have the styles in the HTML section and not the CSS section?

Comment: @Tiffany no specific reason for having two sections, just the way i learned how to do a dropdown. Same goes for style, i like to edit that specific element within the html to not jump around css and html, i can always copy-paste it in the css later. So any suggestions or further questions regarding my work process?

Comment: Your biggest problem is that there are parts of your code that aren't semantic, or don't follow best practices.  Throw your HTML through [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/), and fix the HTML errors that are found.  All of your styles should be in the CSS section, and since a lot of the classes in your style tags are repeated, you don't need two.  The classes from the last style section are going to overwrite the first.  Read about [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Answer (score 2):

Both dropdowns have the same id: "**myDropdown**", change one of them and they will be seen and positioned on different places. (it's really bad to have elements with the same id on a page).

To furthermore position them, change their css position from '**fixed**' to '**absolute**', you can then experiment with the **top**, **left**, **right**, **bottom** to find a nice spot (this is easily achievable since their parent elements have a position set to '**relative**', and all of their childs will be positioned absolutely refering to them instead of the window itself).

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped me a lot to separate the two elements. Now i get the following: https://gyazo.com/1b673591082b226cd3df7b8e77101773 , and I'm assuming this is the styling issue, yet I can't necessarily locate what is causing them to be different, since the code for both is the same.